# Game Theory based on Grundy Numbers

Tags: game-theory

Two players A and B playing a game both players play alternately and optimally starting from A. In each turn, a player can remove **1 $\leq$ cards $\leq$ k** cards from the pile. Player moving the last move win the game. Find the winner. Here **1 $\leq$ k $\leq$ n**.

In this question i tried my approach by finding Mex function for all Grundy numbers then by taking XOR of all Grundy numbers if XOR of all numbers is not equal to zero then Player A wins the game otherwise Player B wins.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Can you please help me in this question MichaelRozenberg?

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, edit please your post and show your attempts. Otherwise, this topic would be deleted.

Comment: @PRINCEGUPTA So what are the Grundy numbers that you found for, say, $k=3$?

Comment: Let suppose n=6 and k=3 then Grundy number will be calculated by taking Mex i.e. set of numbers containing non negative numbers that is not in the set. So Grundy numbers for n=1 G(1)=1,n=2 G(2)=2,n=3 G(3)=3,n=4 G(4)=1 ,n=5 G(5)=2 and for n=6 G(6)=3.

Comment: You should start with $n=0$, then $G(0)=0$. Moreover, are you sure that $G(4)=1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k=3$ then you correctly computed $G(1)=1$, $G(2)=2$, and $G(3)=3$, but $$G(4)=\text{mex}(\{G(1),G(2),G(3)\})=\text{mex}(\{1,2,3\})=0.$$

Hint. Show that for a given $k$, the Grundy function $G$ is periodic of period $k+1$. Note that $G(0)=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try to implement this

Comment: Please, let me know your progress with it.